# Searching a string of text and copying following data in Python

Tags: python

I have a string of data as below:

```
data-name="Stacey" data-s="Smith" data-name="Bradley" data-s="Lomax"
```

and I'd like to be able to search the txt file for data-name and the output be

```
Stacey 
Bradley
```

I know how to print the full line, but I just want to print the key bits of info.

Comment: So what have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `re` module:

```
>>> import re
>>> string
'data-name="Stacey" data-s="Smith" data-name="Bradley" data-s="Lomax"'
>>> print '\n'.join(re.findall(r'(?<=data-name\=\")[^"]+(?=\")', string))
Stacey
Bradley
```

Comment: Thanks so much - this is perfect. Just wondering if you might know why if I choose to write:
s = '\n'.join(re.findall(r'(?<=data-name\=\")[^"]+(?=\")', string))
and then
print len(s)
the output is 14 rather than 2??
Thanks!

Comment: @Vandrew I am outside right now so can't check but if my answer solved the problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left of my answer so that this issue can be marked as solved..

Comment: Sure - thanks for your help. If you have any idea why the length of the list s is coming up as 14, please let me know. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Vandrew Yeah..the reason is you have `join`-ed the members of list and make a string I.e. `s` is a string and `len` of `s` is number of characters in Stacey, Bradley plus a newline..to get what you want just do: `s_list = re.findall(r'(?<=data-name\=\")[^"]+(?=\")', string)` and then get `len(s_list)`

Comment: Amazing - thanks so much, that's helped me heaps.

Answer (score 1):

You can split on the " :

```
s.split('"')[1]
```

will give you "Stacey" because

```
print s.split('"')
#outputs 
["data-name=", "Stacey", " data-s", "Smith", ...]
```

If you want to pick every other one :

```
s.split('"')[1::2] #picks indexes 1, 3, 5, ...
```

will give you ["Stacey", "Bradley"]

If your input is more complicated than you showed, regexp are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

To extend on Sildar's answer given here, you could create a dictionary with all the values belonging to a certain key as follows:

```
map = dict()
splitted = s.split(' ') # Get parts such as 'data-name="Stacey"'
for s in splitted:
  keyvalpair = s.split('=')
  key = keyvalpair[0] # This will be 'data-name'
  val = keyvalpair[1] # You might want to remove the " still, as it now says '"Stacey"'
  if not key in map:
     map[key] = list()
  map[key].append(val)

print map["data-name"]
```